# Throttling error when trying to create web app using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli, throttling

Using the Azure CLI command:

```
az appservice plan create
```

We saw error message:
"App Service Plan operation is throttled for subscription..."

Is there some set limit on the number of commands we can execute on the subscription within a certain time frame?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some set limit on the number of commands we can execute on
> the subscription within a certain time frame?

Yes, there are limits on the number of commands that you can execute at subscription level maximum number for reads & writes at subscription level per hour are reads 12000 & writes 1200.
The default throttling limits per hour are shown in the following table.

[image]

These limits are scoped to the security principal (user or application) making the requests and the subscription ID or tenant ID. If your requests come from more than one security principal, your limit across the subscription or tenant is greater than 12,000 and 1,200 per hour.

Throttling happens at two levels. Azure Resource Manager throttles requests for the subscription and tenant. If the request is under the throttling limits for the subscription and tenant, Resource Manager routes the request to the resource provider. The resource provider applies throttling limits that are tailored to its operations.

You can refer this documentation for more information about [Throttling  Resource Manager requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling) .